# Purpose of email at the end of SSH public key

Tags: ssh, authentication

I was adding one of my public keys to the `authorized_keys` on one of my servers when I realized that at the end of my public SSH key there is my email:

```
$ cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAA[...lots of characters...]bpL johndoe@gmail.com
```

- Why is my email address at the end of the key?
- Does it have any specific purpose?
- Can I write anything I want in my `authorized_keys` file? Like for instance:

  ```
  ssh-rsa AAAA[...lots of characters...]bpL John Doe (Home PC)
  ```

Comment: This is the comment field, so yes, you could put anything there.  Its purpose is solely to help the user identify keys, particularly after they are concatenated into an `authorized_keys` file on a server.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Most likely to identify who created the key.
2. It is just a comment. But as said at 1: probably so you know you created it. Useful when more than 1 administrator is administrating the system.
3. Yes, you can add anything in place of your e-mail. And since it is the last part of it you do not have to use anything special for spaces etc.

   Extra: `ssh-keygen -c` to change it for RSA1 keys (only works for RSA1).